# Perl - unknown end of line character

Tags: perl, eol, file-processing

I want to read an input file line by line, but **this file has unknown ending character**.

Editor `vim` does not know it either, it represents this character as  `^A` and immediately starts with characters from new line. The same is for `perl`. It tried to load all lines in once, because it ignores these strange end of line character.

How can I set this character as end of line for perl? I don't want to use any special module for it (because of our strict system), I just want to define the character (maybe in `hex` code) of end of line.

The another option is to convert the file to another one, with good end of line character (replace them).  Can I make it in some easy way (something like `sed` on input file)? But everything need to be done in perl.

It is possible?

Now, my reading part looks like:

```
open (IN, $in_file);
$event=<IN>;   # read one line
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^A` character you mention is the "start of heading" character. You can set the special Perl variable `$/` to this character. Although, if you want your code to be readable and editable by the guy who comes after you (and uses another editor), I would do something like this:

```
use English;

local $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\cA" # 'start of heading' character

while (<>)
{
    chomp; # remove the unwanted 'start of heading' character
    print $_ . "\n";
}
```

From [Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR):

> $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR
>   $/
>
> The input record separator, newline by default. This influences Perl's idea of what a "line" is.

More on [special character escaping](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=String%20Literals%20in%20Perl) on PerlMonks.

Oh and if you want, you can enter the "start of heading" character in VI, **in insert mode**, by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

edit: added `local` per Drt's suggestion

Comment: Thanks! It works very well :) Thanks for explanation of ^A character, I needed it.

Comment: while using `$/` do use it like `local $/ = '^A'`. Because it's a built-in special variable and `local` will change it for that block only and will not affect other part of script.

Comment: `^A` represents the "start of heading" character (`"\cA"` aka `chr(0x01)`). A line feed (`"\cJ"` aka `chr(0x0A)`) would be represented using `^J` in that notation.

Comment: Also, `"\n"` is not platform specific. `"\n"` results in a newline (`chr(0x0A)`) on all existing platforms.

Comment: Strange, when I tested the code above (I ran it through `hd` to check the output), I'm sure my system said `0a` for `^A`. That was on Ubuntu Hardy. Now I'm testing on Ubuntu Precise, and it says `01`, as you are stating. Although that's a really strange line separation character.

By the way, in Perl, `"\n"` *is* platform specific ([source](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Newlines)). But since it's no longer relevant, I'll leave the post as it is.